# Calculate date of birth SQL DB2 and indicate bad data

Tags: sql, db2, subquery

I am trying to calculate the age at the time of students admission. I have tried this query, but in some cases I have admission date is prior to their date of birth (bad data).

For example:

```
date of birth is 2016-10-22-00.00.00.000000 
admission date is 2016-09-09-14.51.00.000000
```

I am getting 0, but I should get something with the (-) negative number, so I can see this is bad data. Thank you

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT student_id, 
               Timestampdiff(256, Char(Timestamp(admission_date) - 
                                       Timestamp(date_of_birth))) 
               AS Admission_DOB 
        FROM   person) AS a 
WHERE  admission_dob <= '10'
```

Comment: I'd use a case statement

Comment: why you convert timestamp difference to `CHAR()`?

Comment: The datatype for date of birth and admission date are TIMESTAMP

Comment: If there is better way please share it. I found somewhere this query to calculate the age.

Comment: Im not familiar with db2. But you shouldnt use `TIMESTAMP()` if your fields are already timestamp or comvert to char the result

Comment: It works if I convert

Answer (score 0):

You should solve this as separated issues. One for calculate age, and the other to find bad data.

So find bad data should be  simpler like:

```
SELECT *, 'good data', age(start, end) as age
FROM  person
WHERE admission_date > date_of_birth

UNION ALL

SELECT *, 'bad data', null as age -- or age(end, start)
FROM  person
WHERE admission_date < date_of_birth
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Juan. But I need it in one query, so I can present one report to my customers.

Comment: what if you use union all? check my edit for the general idea ...`age()` is your function to calculate age

Comment: Thank you Juan. I found a way to resolve this. Posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT student_id, 
   CASE admission_date > date_of_birth THEN 
     Timestampdiff(256, Char(Timestamp(admission_date)-Timestamp(date_of_birth))) 

   ELSE 
      Timestampdiff(256, Char(Timestamp(date_of_birth)-Timestamp(admission_date))) 

           AS Admission_DOB 
    FROM   person
```

Comment: I just post the answer which helps me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user470091 -- that is not very much in the spirit of this site -- you posted a question which was impossible to answer and then stole my code and modified it with information that only you know to "answer" your question.   It seems I answered your question -- don't you think?

Comment: Yours answered helped me but was still giving 0 instead of any negative number so I can see in the results easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT student_id,  
               CASE WHEN  ar.DT_ACCESS_RCVD <  p.DT_BRTH 
                    THEN '-9' 
                    ELSE  Timestampdiff(256, Char(Timestamp(admission_date) - 
                                                  Timestamp(date_of_birth))) 
               END AS Admission_DOB 
        FROM   person) AS a 
WHERE  admission_dob <= '10'
```

Comment: To format as `code`, select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line